# YIi2 get records not contained in another table

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

I would like to retrieve records in one table not contained in another

I have two tables

```
tb_users having columns
   id(primary key) 
   username, 
   firstname, 

2. tbl_paychecks
     id(primary key)
     user_id(foreignkey)
     amount
     created_at
     ...
```

NOw i would like to retrieve all the users without paychecks that it all tbl_users whose id's are not in the tbl_paychecks

So in my users model

```
public function getNOPaychecks()
  {
    return self::find()
      ->leftJoin('tbl_paychecks','`tbl_paychecks`.`user_id` != `tbl_user`.`id`')
       ->where(['tbl_paycheks.user_id'=>null])
       ->all();
   }
```

But the above still returns an error of

```
unknown column tbl_paycheks.user_id in 'where clause
```

Where am i going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You have a type in yout table name tbl_`paycheks` instead of `tbl_paychecks`and  for null you could use is

```
public function getNOPaychecks()
{
  return self::find()
    ->leftJoin('tbl_paychecks','`tbl_paychecks`.`user_id` != `tbl_user`.`id`')
     ->where(['is', 'tbl_paychecks.user_id', null])
     ->all();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why your code is not working.Try doing it as two queries.

```
public function getNOPaychecks()
{
   $paycheckUsers = ArrayHelper::getColumn(PayCheckModelClassName::find()->select(['user_id'])->asArray()->all(),'user_id');
   return self::find()
      ->where(['NOT IN','id',$paycheckUsers])
      ->all();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use 'exists' or 'not exists'  operator in your Query
try this:

```
 public function getNOPaychecks()
  {
        $subQuery = (new Query())->select('*')->from('tbl_paycheks' . ' t2')->where(
            't2.user_id=t2.user_id'
        );

    return self::find()
      ->alias('t1')
       ->where(['not exists',$subQuery])
       ->all();
   }
```